# Upload large file to Sourceforge

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I just make a project in  [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/) and I want to upload some file to   my project page with 1.5GB size, but I can't do this with normal way because it's allow me to upload files with 1GB size.

How can I do this with `scp` or `rsync` in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jebi3sG9n7Y), you can use `rsync` with SSH as the remote shell:

```
rsync -avP -e ssh /path/to/local/files sourceforge_username@frs.sourceforge.net:/home/frs/project/sourceforge_project_name
```

Replace `sourceforge_username` and `sourceforge_project_name` with your SourceForge details, and use your SourceForge password for the SSH password.

The video has more step-by-step information for doing this with Grsync, an rsync GUI